# How to exclude some files from copy that also match specified wildcard in batch

Tags: batch-file, filesystems, copy-paste

I am not very experienced in batch. I have some files that look like this:

```
foo-spoon-a.bar
foo-spoon-b-a.bar
foo-fork-a.bar
foo-fork-b-a.bar
foo-knife-a.bar
foo-knife-b-a.bar
```

I want to copy each of the foo-*-a files to `\folderA` and all the foo-*-b-a folders to `\folderBA`. Copy works normally on `folderBA`. However, when I use copy on `folderA`:

`for /R "original_folder" %%f in ("foo-*-a.bar") do copy /Y %%f "folderA"`

The program copies the a files but it also copies the b-a files because they still match the wildcard. Is there a way to copy all of the files at once and paste half of them in one folder and half in the other folder? Or copy half of the files and then copy the other ones that were not already copied? What is the simplest solution that takes **the least code**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /R "original_folder" %%f in ("foo-*-a.bar") do echo "%%~nxf"|findstr /L /I "-b-a" >nul& if errorlevel 1 (copy /Y %%f "folderB") else (copy /Y %%f "folderA")
```

recommend you try against a dummy fileset first, with the `copy` replaced by `echo(copy` to show rather than actually copy the files.

Method: echo the name and extension of the file into `findstr` which then `/L` literally `/i` case-insensitively finds the string `-b-a`. If the string is found, `errorlevel` becomes 0, if not, 1

The `if` then operates on the `errorlevel` set by the `findstr`.

Comment: you can just use conditional execution after findstr and remove the if condition.

Comment: I ended up switching to this answer because it fits what I need better. O also ended up having to remove the first - from "-b-a" in the script because it was causing errors. I also had to switch the folders in the if/else errorlevel check.

Answer (score 2):

try to filter with findstr or find (which will require `for /f`)

```
  for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s "original_folder\foo-*-a.bar" ^| find /i /v "-b-a.bar"') do copy /Y %%f "folderA"
```

Comment: Thank you, this one was the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

What about this: copying all `foo-*-a.bar` files to `folderA`, then moving all `foo-*-b-a.bar` files from `folderA` to `folderBA` (remember that moving is quick as the data are actually not moved)?

```
for /R "original_folder" %%f in ("foo-*-a.bar") do copy /Y "%%~f" "folderA\"
for /R "folderA" %%f in ("foo-*-b-a.bar") do move /Y "%%~f" "folderBA\"
```